# Does the wrapper class for a thread safe object also need to be made thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

[I didn't find any satisfactory answer to this hence posting a question.]

Suppose I have a thread safe C++ class "ThreadSafeClass". Now, I have written a wrapper over it "MyWrapper". MyWrapper does not have any other data member. I have a couple of doubts here:

1. Does the individual methods of this wrapper class also need to be protected by a mutex to make them thread safe? Or is it safe to assume that since the underlying object is thread safe so there is no need?
2. If the answer to <1> above is no (no mutex needed in the wrapper) then consider this: We do not protect the wrapper class via any mutex assuming the access to the only underlying object would always be thread safe. Now suppose 1 thread is in the destructor of the wrapper object while another thread is accessing its member function (assuming the wrapper class did not have any mutex to avoid this situation). Is it possible that the thread safe object has been destroyed by one thread and then the other thread tries to access it? I know this sounds a little weird and most probably I am missing something but this depends on the answer to <1> above.

   ```
   class MyWrapper {
   private:
       ThreadSafeClass _ts_obj;
   public:
       void foo()
       {
           _ts_obj.do_something();
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: You don't  need a additional `mutex` in this case.

Comment: Calling the method, directly with the same class object or indirectly through a wrapper that contains the object are equally safe. The notion of one thread being in the destructor of the wrapper is similar to one thread being in the destructor of the object as it will also be destructed. It is not a good idea to have one thread operating on a class object while another is destructing it.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by the term "thread safe object".

Comment: The point you make in #2 sounds like a wrong design. You should have some sort of deterministic lifetime management so that you `join` on threads before the instance of `MyWrapper` goes out of scope..

Comment: @Galik What I mean is assume that the object is of a class which has been designed with proper thread synchronization in mind. In my particular use case, it is the log4cplus::Logger class which is thread safe and I intent to write a wrapper over it.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, in the given scenario you don't have to protect your wrapper class with additional mutex
2. When multiple threads use the same object you should be very careful to manage the object lifetime, so that one thread cannot destroy the object while it's accessed by the others. The easiest you can do is to use `shared_ptr<Wrapper>` smart pointer in the threads to access the data. This is thread safe reference counting smart pointer that will destroy the object once it's not referenced from any thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. No you don't need additional mutex layer.
2. If you share object between two threads you need to pass object as reference/pointer. In this case thread destructor will only clean the reference/pointer, but own delete object underlying so everything is ok. If you would be passing object as copy also everything is fine.

Edit:
of course if you force deletion of object underlying under pointer you'll have segmentation fault.